# Fastest way to read in and print back out a 2d array in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code works for reading in a 2d array and printing it back out in Kotlin, however I imagine that with larger datasets swapping from a string to an int list would be rather slow, so is there a quicker way to do it?

```
fun main() {
    var rowAndColumn = readLine()!!.split(" ")
    var rows = rowAndColumn[0].toInt()
    var columns = rowAndColumn[1].toInt()
    val board = Array(rows) { IntArray(columns).toMutableList() }
    for (i in 0 until rows) {
        var stringColumn = readLine()!!.split("").toMutableList()
        stringColumn.removeAll(listOf(""))
        var column = stringColumn.map {it.toInt()}.toMutableList()
        board[i] = column

    }
    for(i in 0 until rows) {
        println(board[i].toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the whole input space delineated integers? Is the final array always rectangular, or are the rows of variable size?

Comment: No the array is not space delimited and yes the final array is always rectangular. A sample input would be:                                                              10 20
11111111111111111111
11000000000000000101
11111111111111110000
11111111111111110000
11000000000000000111
00011111111111111111
00111111111111111111
10000000000000001111
11111111111111111111
11111111111111111111    with the spacing representing lines

Comment: So integers that you read are all from 0-9?

Comment: No they are just zeroes and ones. To be very specific I am trying to solve this kattis problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/10kindsofpeople

Comment: I just tried it and can't get mine to do it in time. I was using flood fill, but maybe A* is better. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I measure this to be about 4-5 times faster than your method. It iterates Chars rather than splitting each line into Strings for each character.

```
var rowAndColumn = readLine()!!.split(" ")
var rows = rowAndColumn[0].toInt()
var columns = rowAndColumn[1].toInt()
val board = arrayOfNulls<IntArray?>(rows)
for (row in 0 until rows) {
    board[row] = readLine()!!
        .asIterable()
        .mapNotNull {
            val i = it.toInt() - '0'.toInt()
            if (i in 0..1) i else null
        }
        .toIntArray()
}
board.requireNoNulls()
```

If you you don't mind ending up with an `Array<List<Int>>` instead of an `Array<IntArray>`, you can change that out on line 4 and remove the `.toIntArray()` call for a slight (~5%) improvement.

Caveat...I was reading from a text file, not the console input, so file access may have affected the comparison. Intuition tells me it's possible this would be even faster in comparison if file reading time were removed.